# Android Tune TCP flow control on Smart phones?

Tags: android, tcp

I am new to ANdroid development (but have worked on linux)..We can tune TCP parameters(window size..etc) to get better performance on desktop's either windows or linux.

Was wondering can we do the same on andriod based smart phones? ...i was informed that only on root access devices we can do it...how about non-root access devices?

This for all TCP based connections initiated from android device and not specific to a socket.
I was solution something similar to what we do desktop/laptop's ....i.e configure the TCP parameters in the OS example increasing windo size. so that any further connections started/initiated from the box would use that as the default value...
Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you aren't working with an app, you want the whole system(2g/3g/4g/wifi etc.) to move faster, correct?

In that case you must be rooted and the solution to your question is to flash a custom kernel that supports those options in its network stack.

With a custom kernel you can easily set the TCP congestion algorithm to your preference.

Comment: Yes this is one of the option. But wanted to explore option of without  building custom kernal, What i am looking for is to build an app..which everyone can download and tune it accordingly ...based on the net speed they get

Comment: you wouldn't have to build the kernel, there are many custom kernels available, just browse the XDA forums for your device.     Regarding a app that speeds up TCP, there are a handful out on the market (just google for them) but I don't know if they work or are just placebos.

Answer (score 0):

There are `Socket.setSendBufferSize()` and `Socket.setReceiveBufferSize()`. I don't see any reason why root privileges should be required.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was looking for across TCP connections....i.e for all the Wifi(if possible 3g/4g) based tcp connections ....and not specific to a socket connection.edited the question